# Defining a lazy stream in Scala (translating a Racket example)

Tags: scala, racket

I was learning Racket (University of Washington Programming Languages course on Coursera) and there is an interesting example to define a lazy stream of values in Racket:

```
(define ones
  (lambda () (cons 1 ones)))
```

Basically this defines a function `ones` that returns a lambda that when called returns a tuple that the first element is 1 and the second element is the method itself.

I was trying to define this function in Scala but cannot get the typing right, there is some weird recursion going on:

```
def ones = () => (1, ones) // This complains that recursive function should have types
def ones: () => (Int, ???) = () => (1, ones) // What is the type here?
```

What's the correct type for this function?

Comment: How about `def ones: Iterator[Int] = Iterator(1) ++ ones` ? Or `def ones: () => Iterator[Int] = () => Iterator(1) ++ ones()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically this defines a function ones that returns a lambda that when
> called **returns a tuple that the first element is 1 and the second
> element is the method itself.**

[Here we go](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KvNFoW1jTMy46hWdfYRNow): (Do **not** recommend, scala 2.1 only)

```
import scala.language.existentials

type T = () => (Int, () => A) forSome { type A <: (Int, () => A) }

def ones: T = () => (1, ones)

val (i1, f1) = ones()
val (i2, f2) = f1()
val (i3, f3) = f2()

println(i1, i2, i3) // get (1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Actually I was trying something today and such a thing also works: `case class MyTuple(i: Int, next: () => MyTuple)` and `def ones: () => MyTuple = () => MyTuple(1, ones)`. I think your version is the generalized version of this, right?

Comment: Yes, it become much simpler if you relax the `tuple` part to a custom type.

Comment: @Wickoo you may simplify the calling API like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/HopAea5fQO6rzC8X8683Gw/5). But that is not a lambda, nor a tuple so is not what you wanted. - However, if you want that kind of lazy recursion in **Scala** you need a class since type aliases can't be recursive; but that class of yours is basically a re-implementation of the old `Stream` class _(except this one doesn't have an empty one, thus also not an end)_; and `Stream` was deprecated and replaced with `LazyList` because that encoding has some problems.

Comment: This is exactly like the Racket version, no? Only with types. There is a tuple that its second argument is a lambda that is recursive. This is also called a stream in Racket, I just wanted to get the typing right. If Scala streams are typed like this, that’s great.

Comment: @Wickoo _"This is exactly like the Racket version, no?"_ it depends on your definition of exactly the same. If this is the same then my answer is the same since `LazyList` under the hood presents a similar encoding. But you said it was not the same because the **racket** version used a lambda and a tuple only, and your example doesn't do that since it needs an intermediate class just like the `LazyList` class.

Comment: You just showed a library class that does the same thing. In @esse version, and the one I posted, it uses lambdas and tuples to implement the Racket thing. Maybe one level deeper, it is the same thing. At the end it’s just some Java bytecode, so everything is the same

Comment: And here: type T = () => (Int, () => A) forSome { type A <: (Int, () => A) } do you see the lambda and tuple? Or no?

Comment: And that intermediate type or class is the limitation of the type system, racket is untyped of course. That was the question, how to type it, not what Scala experts recommend

Comment: @Wickoo and that stdlib class is just equivalent to what you wrote. `type T = () => (Int, () => A) forSome { type A <: (Int, () => A) }` that is an existential type and will break quite easily, is not recommended and actually I don't even understand why it compiles when a regular recursive type does not. Also,  your example doesn't use tuples, it uses a custom class. And no, your question as defined in the title was how to define a lazy stream, not a recursive lambda. - Anyways, my point is, you were so fixated on the answer you wanted that you didn't see the answer, that is a common mistake.

Comment: I think you described your problem very well, great self reflection.  You already have too many SO points, so can survive without this one ;-) my class is almost a tuple, I hope you see the point. One last thing, Stream is a concept here not the Scala stream. And yes, I like the answer I accepted more, sorry.

Comment: @Wickoo sigh, I don't care about the points, not about what you think about me. What I do care about is you learning something from this. As I said, you were either too fixated to see the answer in a specific way, or bad at communicating what you actually wanted; your third comment on my answer _(removing the unnecessary rudeness)_ was all you need to say to get the answer you wanted. - Actually, when I woke up in the morning and read that comment I was about to edit the answer with the **Scastie** link I shared above, untl I noticed Esse's answer _(which I upvoted)_ and your comment.

Comment: I don’t care about you and what you think/care about, you really tend to make it personal by starting the whole thing why you don’t like my answer… Anyway, thus discussion is over. I have already accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well `(1, ones)` is just a tuple, and a tuple has a fixed size so it can't be infinite, but you can just construct a `LazyList` just like in the **racket** example like this:

```scala
lazy val ones = 1 #:: ones
```

Or even simpler:

```scala
val ones = LazyList.continually(1)
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not the answer to the question. The question was how do you type such a lambda in Scala?

Comment: @Wickoo Depends on what you mean with _"such lambda"_, the first example is exactly the translation of that lambda but you don't like it for some reason that I can't understand.

Comment: Seems like you don’t read the question. The question is fill in the ??? In this definition: def ones: () => (Int, ???) = () => (1, ones) or tell me what’s wrong with this definitin or how it should be fixed, etc. I am not looking for a scala feature that solves it, it’s more about the typing concept here

Comment: @Wickoo it seems you don't read the answers, `(Int, ???)` is a tuple of two elements, a tuple has a fixed size so it won't work for your use case of creating an infinite stream, because you are trying to use a wrong data structure. Just like in **Racket** you need a `LazList` for that. Just like the type of `ones` is `LazyList[Int]`

Comment: Oh man, it’a pointless talking to you, it returns a tuple of an int and a lambda itself, which makes it infinite… you have to get the second element in the tuple, call it to get another tuple, and the first element is the second element of the stream. Did you get the Racket example? Anyway, thanks but I’ll pass and let others chime in

Comment: Racket is an untyped language. You can not simply take a concept in one language & translate into another in the **exact** way you want. There are a lot of things in Racket that doesn't have one to one correspondence in Scala, because well... they are different languages. One is based on lambda calculus, other on Fw. Even though there are constructs in both we refer to as `lambda`, two lambdas are very different under the hood. So tl;dr no this isn't possible in Scala 2 in the exact way you want it. One might suggest F-bounded polymorphism but that's not actually what you want here

Comment: In order to fully appreciate this, try making the same definition in `typed/racket`. Notice why you either need Union types AND the notion of a `Nil` type. Next take a look at how `shapeless` defines `Hlist` and what type restrictions they sacrifice (i.e. observe how it is more general than this and cant be constraint). And if you are really curios, you can research the difference of a lambda in LC vs SystemFw and see why Racket lambdas pack the power they do